# NUnit - Getting results.xml when running tests with Test Adapter in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

When using [`nunit-console.exe`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Console-Runner) to run tests from the command line you can have a `result.xml`file created, which can further be used for example by [ReportUnit](http://relevantcodes.com/reportunit-report-generator/) to create nice looking reports.

## Question

Is there a way to produce this result.xml file when running the tests not via nunit-console but with the [NUnit (3.0) Test Adapter for Visual Studio](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=3.0) via the Test Explorer Window?

At least I wasn't able to find an xml file after the tests finished running, so I assume, that there is none created.

* I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: The visual studio test runner generates a `.trx` file, which holds similar content, but is not compatible with the `jUnit/NUnit` xml format.

Comment: @jessehouwing: thx! that's already a nice tip, I'll have a look at how to parse those, maybe that's already sufficient for now. Still the question holds even though I fear I already know the answer =(

Comment: My suspicion is, no won't do.But this may help: http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/27-trx-to-html-using-xslt

Answer (score 0):

NUnit XML output could be produced by the NUnit console and GUI runners only. You won't get it with Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by specifying the `ResultsDirectory` property in your `.runsettings` file. If you don't have one, check the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2015